# When/how does a topic "marked for deletion" get finally removed?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have issued the command to delete a topic:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic  vip_ips_alerts
```

It seemed to give a happy response:

```
[2014-05-31 20:58:10,112] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
Topic "vip_ips_alerts" queued for deletion.
```

But now 10 minutes later the topic still appears in the `--list` command:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
vip_ips_alerts - marked for deletion
```

So what does that mean?  When will the topic be *really* deleted?  How do I expedite this process?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**tl;dr** Set `delete.topic.enable = true` in `config/server.properties` of Kafka brokers and...be patient.

It happens with the latest development version of Kafka **0.8.3-SNAPSHOT**:

```
➜  kafka_2.11-0.8.3-SNAPSHOT git:(trunk) ✗ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic my-topic --partitions 2 --replication-factor 1
Created topic "my-topic".

➜  kafka_2.11-0.8.3-SNAPSHOT git:(trunk) ✗ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic my-topic
Topic:my-topic  PartitionCount:2    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: my-topic Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: my-topic Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0

➜  kafka_2.11-0.8.3-SNAPSHOT git:(trunk) ✗ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic my-topic
Topic my-topic is marked for deletion.
Note: This will have no impact if delete.topic.enable is not set to true.

➜  kafka_2.11-0.8.3-SNAPSHOT git:(trunk) ✗ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
➜  kafka_2.11-0.8.3-SNAPSHOT git:(trunk) ✗
```

The point is to have `delete.topic.enable=true` in `config/server.properties` that you use to start a Kafka broker.

```
➜  kafka_2.11-0.8.3-SNAPSHOT git:(trunk) ✗ grep delete.topic.enable config/server.properties
delete.topic.enable=true
```

You can also ensure the setting be true in a broker's log:

```
➜  kafka_2.11-0.8.3-SNAPSHOT git:(trunk) ✗ ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
[2015-07-24 22:33:26,184] INFO KafkaConfig values:
        ...
        delete.topic.enable = true
```

Comment: "be patient" is somewhat imprecise - I'm sitting here hours after restarting the brokers (0.8.2) and waiting for those topics to disappear, but having a rough guideline of when they'll actually be gone would be helpful. Will they stick around for the full seven days of log.retention?

Comment: After being patient for a week, I assume the answer in the linked comment is in fact correct: If "delete.topic.enable = true" wasn't set during creation of the topic, it will not be taken into account for deletion.

Comment: I was having that problem, but after modify the server.properties and restart kafka and zookeeper the log showed the topic been deleted

Comment: Looks like a capability added since the OP from May '14

Comment: Please mind that delete.topic.enable is now true by default since 1.0. version - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5384

Comment: It seems also that all the consumers of the topic need to be stopped before the topic will actually be reaped.

Comment: I have a topic "marked for deletion" for over a day. I can't "be patient" indefinitely. I need to get the topic deleted and move forward with work tasks.

Comment: @clay What's the version of Kafka?

Comment: Kafka 2.0.0 + Confluent Platform 5.0.0

Comment: @clay Deletion should work out of the box and nearly instant. Check out the configuration of the brokers

Answer (score 32):

In my case where i am using Kafka 8.2.2, I had to delete entries from the following manually -

1. Delete topic folder from Kafka broker machine.
2. Login to zookeeper and -

   ```
   hbase zkcli
   rmr /brokers/topics/{topic_name}
   rmr /admin/delete_topics/{topic_name}
   ```

Comment: Only this worked for me, used rmr commands only. Using Kafka 11.0.1, topic to be deleted was created before setting delete.topic.enable to true. Removing logs, restarting didn't work, as topic stayed "marked for deletion"

Answer (score 20):

You can do it.

> sudo ./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 rmr /brokers/topics/your_topic

Answer (score 16):

I faced the same issue and spend a couple of days trying to identify with the issue was. I triggered command to delete the topics, however the topics were marked for deletion but they were not deleted.

1. I first checked the configuration which are set right. Under: server.properties

   > delete.topic.enable=true for all brokers
2. I restarted the broker to check if the topics got delete (No!!).
3. I check no data under /kafka/data folder.
4. I even considered the option to wait until the retention time got exceed.

None helped. I had to finally login to zooker

```
./zkCli.sh # and delete the topics using 
rmr /brokers/topics/<<topic>> and rmr /admin/delete_topics/<<topic>>
```

Please remember to restart kafka after this.
Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Holy ****. Thanks for this!

Comment: Also, might I add, rebooting Kafka wasn't necessary, at least for me.

Comment: Yes, this worked quickly for me, without needing reboot. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is actually the following.  HOT off the Kafka-user's group email distribution list:

> François Langelier *@gmail.com über kafka.apache.org  05:57
>   (vor 1 Stunde)
>
> an users  The delete topic isn't working ATM
>
> I think it will be available in the next release
>   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1397

Comment: and by the way it pops up on 0.8.1.1 version -- we recently made an upgrade (from 0.8.1) to it and observing problem as well

Answer (score 3):

My issue was something similar.
I deleted a topic and it was giving me the same message when I was listing all the topics.

I brought down the zookeeper and the broker.
set the delete.topic.enable=true in my broker config file
started zookeeper and the boker

The topic was gone...thanks to Jacek Laskowski

Answer (score 3):

## 2021/22 - rmr is deprecated, use deleteall

### 1. Login to Zookeeper:

#### Linux

Go to **bin** folder:

```
.\zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181
```

#### Windows

Go to **bin\windows** folder:

```
.\zookeeper-shell.bat localhost:2181
```

### 2. Delete topic

```
deleteall /brokers/topics/NameOfTopicToDelete
```

**No need to run anymore:**
deleteall  /admin/delete_topics/NameOfTopicToDelete

Restart zookeeper and kafka. If you try to delete topic now you will get:

> Node does not exist error.

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue when deleting topics. The topics had been created when delete.topic.enable=true had not been set. We set that in config, restarted kafka to apply the new config. Deleted the topics and saw the "marked for deletion". We then restarted kafka again. After 40 minutes though all topics had been deleted (9 topics with total partitions in the thousands). The topics with higher numbers of partitions seemed to take longer, which initially made it look like nothing was happening.

Answer (score 2):

For kafka version `0.10.0.0` it is enough to enable the topic deletion by setting:

```
delete.topic.enable
```

The topic is deleted within few moments

```
kafka-topics --delete --zookeeper your-zk:2181 --topic yourTopicName
```

You can confirm that it is gone with the following command:

```
kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper your-zk:2181 --topic yourTopicName
```

Answer (score 2):

Check status of topic at zookeeper

```
bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
Output: topic shows marked for deletion
```

Setting *delete.topic.enable=true* in *server.properties* was not working as well.

**Solution:**
Check the zookeeper data directory location in zookeeper.properties file. 
it was *dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper*. 
Issue got resolved after updating "dataDir" to a new location.

```
dataDir=zk-temp
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
```

Answer (score 1):

The deletion happened for me almost immediately (v 0.9). I believe that it should be the same for you.

Once marked, the deletion will be triggered on the kafka node which is the topic partition leader. The thing to remember is that the the topic partition leader must be configured correctly (in terms of listeners), otherwise it will not receive the instruction to delete the logs.

I had my "marked for deletion" topics stuck at that state until I corrected my server properties and restarted the respective node.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing worked above , You can try below :

`First, log into the Zookeeper CLI console using the proper ‘zkCli.sh’ file,  you’ll find this in the ‘bin’ directory in your Zookeeper installation.`

`2.  get /brokers/topics/<topic_name>`

`3. rmr /brokers/topics/<topic_name>`

`4. rmr /admin/delete_topics/<topic_name>`

Answer (score -2):

In Kafka, once the topic is marked for deletion, it will get finally removed after 60000 milliseconds.

Check the property log.segment.delete.delay.ms.

The documentation says:

> file.delete.delay.ms: The time to wait before deleting a file from the
>   filesystem Default value is 60000 ms.