# Kafka topic deletion not working

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka version 0.8.2. In the middle of development I thought I might need to delete a topic. So what I did is I put the following line in the server configuration files and started two kafka servers.

```
delete.topic.enable=true
```

When I needed to delete a topic and I ran following command,

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic MyTopic
```

Right now its already 17 hours since when I ran delete topic command but Kafka is still showing me the topic is marked for deletion. Is it a bug of Kafka or I am doing something wrong here? Because it doesn't seem normal to me. Can someone clarify in this regard?

[N.B.: I have already read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976670/when-how-does-a-topic-marked-for-deletion-get-finally-removed). But couldn't find my answer there.]

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is not possible to delete kafka topic if you previously had `delete.topic.enable=false`. You can change this value, but it does not affect currently available topics. So, you can try to delete it manually.

Comment: This answer would be awesomely helpful if validated!

Comment: So, a week (with 7 days retention configured) later and my "marked deleted" topic still hasn't disappeared. This makes me think you are indeed correct.

Comment: @RickMoritz yes, I think so :)

Comment: I just found out that you can delete the topics by manually deleting the log folders and files.

Comment: for me, deleting logs & restart didn't help (topic created before setting delete.topic.enable), but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34050408/2652734) helped. Solution involves using zookeeper shell.

Comment: when you set delete.topic.enable, it should delete. But having a ZK shell helps

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the log folder location and manually delete the files concerning the topic you want to delete.