# How can I remove Kafka topics marked for deletion

Tags: apache-kafka

I have several Kafka topics I used as tests. Now I want to get rid of them all by cleaning up my kafka topic list.
I set the variable `delete.topic.enable=true`, I stopped and restarted the zookeeper and kafka servers. But nothing helped me. The topics are still there, 'marked for deletion'.
I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976670/when-how-does-a-topic-marked-for-deletion-get-finally-removed), but didn't find any answer. 
Otherwise, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094746/kafka-topic-deletion-not-working) it is suggested to remove manually any topic. But how do I do that?
At the end of the story, manually or by command line, how do I remove Kafka topics for good?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976670/when-how-does-a-topic-marked-for-deletion-get-finally-removed may help you

Comment: As I have written in my question, I already checked that question. It's the first that pops up if you search. The problem is that even if I restart the server and set the variable, the topics are still there. Do you know how to help me?

Comment: Do you try to modify the server.properties and restart kafka and zookeeper

Comment: Another post is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094746/kafka-topic-deletion-not-working

Comment: Yes, I have set `delete.topic.enable=true` and restarted everything. It's all still there. Since days ago. As I have written in the question, I have read also the second link you provided.

Comment: @Jacky I solved my issue. By the way, your comments just show that you haven't read the question since you posted linked to already-read questions. This is not helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it: it is enough to manually delete the folders which contains all the logs from Zookeeper and Kafka servers.